# showing a grandtotal of values in a field

Tags: php, select, field

good pm. i was thinking is it possible to show the summation or grand total of a selected field in the table and with relation to date:

for example is i want to know the total beer consumption of my hotel every month.

i have here my table on services:

```
[services_id[pk],
customer_id[fk],
date_in,date_out,room_type,room_number,
extra_ref,
extra_bed,extra_snack,
extra_beer,extra_softdrinks,
extra_pillows,extra_breakfast,
extra_snack_q,
extra_beer_q,
extra_softdrinks_q,
extra_pillows_q,
extra_breakfast_q]
```

can you give some advice on how can i get it.
thanks in advance:

-renz

Comment: on which dbms is you app running? (MySQL, SQL Server...)

Comment: in mysql bro xammp to be exact

Comment: Not related to your question, but you should consider normalizing your tables : http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization

Comment: @JohnP thanks again ill take a note to this. im still new on php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT SUM(beer_amount) as monthly_beer_amount
FROM [DATABASE].[TABLE] 
WHERE beer_sold_date BETWEEN '20110201' AND '20110228'
```

**[EXTRA INFO]**

Also I believe that the best way to organize this table is to separate out this table into a few other tables. Store customer info in the first table such as

```
[customer_id, customer_name, date_in, date_out, room_type, room_number]. 
1, Bob, 20110101, 20110110, big, 200
2, Joe, 20110101, 20110110, small, 202
....
```

And have another table named something like room_items which would have the following,

```
[id, item_name]
1, BEER
2, BED
3, SNACK
...
```

And then another table named room_purchases which will have the following,

```
[customer_id, purchase_id, amount, date....]
1, 1, 10, 20110101
2, 3, 5, 20110101
3, 1, 9, 20110101
....
```

This would help you to do a join on all three tables and they would be more normalized in this way.

```
SELECT SUM(t2.amount) as beer_amount
FROM customers as t1 
LEFT JOIN room_purchases as t2 ON t1.customer_id = t2.customer_id
WHERE t2.purchase_id = 1 AND t2.date BETWEEN 20110101 AND 20110131
```

Comment: there are both date_in and date_out to deal with, but this is the idea anyway :)

Comment: @metro thanks for your fast reply. i got a question on your code should i add a monthly_beer on my table ?

Comment: @renz To me what really matters in this case is when the beer is being bought and how much its being bought for. It does not matter who is buying it. So the date_in, date_out should not be what you go off of. So, yes some sort of monthly beer, or daily beer amounts would be what you need to check this. I will update my query to make this a little more clear.

Comment: Yup, i understand, but the thing is, we don't know **when** the beer was bought. We just have a date_in and date_out value, the guy can buy two beers the first day and no more until he leaves.If you have two month crossing in just one DB line, you cannot know if beers were buy on the first month or on the second. Whch makes it almost impossible to have proper stats about it.

Comment: But we could easily know when the beer was bought. Its just a matter of creating another table to hold these values separate from the customers. I really do not think that many of these values should be intermingled with the customer data. If I was creating these tables I would do it more normalized as johnP suggested. When the guy buys 2 beers on the first day, you store that date with the amount he paid in another table.

Comment: @renz I updated my answer to show you a nicer way to organize your tables for this problem. Of course it can be done many ways, and this may not be the best, but it would be more normalized and more efficient.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(date_in,"%m-%Y") AS month,SUM(extra_beer) AS beers
FROM your_table
GROUP BY month
```

this will return something like this:

```
02-2011 | 43
03-2011 | 52
```

if you want to limit the query depending on the date just add a `WHERE` constraint before the `GROUP BY`